Does Ubuntu OVAL list packages that are vulnerable (have CVE) but are not yet patched (have no USN)?
The Ubuntu documentation recommends using Ubuntu OVAL to track packages that are vulnerable and you should upgrade. In the final section "How Ubuntu OVAL data works" it states (emphasis mine)

As software vulnerabilities are discovered, they are assigned CVE identifiers by MITRE and other organizations. Canonical triages these CVEs to determine whether the vulnerabilities affect software distributed within Ubuntu. The results of this triage are then used to generate the CVE OVAL. The CVE OVAL can be used to assess the local system for vulnerabilities.
When the Ubuntu Security Team patches software to address one or more CVEs, an Ubuntu Security Notice (USN) is published announcing the update. The USN OVAL data is generated  from information encapsulated within the USN, and can be used to assess the system for missing patches.

So CVEs only get an USN when they're patched. Does the latest OVAL list all CVEs of current packages, even those that do are not yet patched and thus have no USNs, or does it only list patches?

Short Answer : Yes
The CVE oval file has more information than the USN oval file. You can validate this
CVE-2023-35936
still mentions "Needs Evaluation" for all releases. This means the CVE has not yet been analyzed in detail from the security team to release a patch.
In the CVE oval - we can see its detection being just checking if pandoc is installed
$ wget https://security-metadata.canonical.com/oval/com.ubuntu.noble.cve.oval.xml.bz2
$ bunzip2 com.ubuntu.noble.cve.oval.xml.bz2
$ grep CVE-2023-35936 com.ubuntu.noble.cve.oval.xml
        <title>CVE-2023-35936 on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (noble) - medium</title>
...

The logic
      <criteria>
        <extend_definition definition_ref="oval:com.ubuntu.noble:def:100" comment="Ubuntu 24.04 LTS is installed." applicability_check="true"/>
        <criteria operator="OR">
          <criterion test_ref="oval:com.ubuntu.noble:tst:2023359360000000" comment="pandoc package in noble is affected and may need fixing."/>
        </criteria>
      </criteria>

